# "ERROR 000840: The value is not a Data Element" while scripting Rename_management

Tags: arcpy, error-000840

I am trying to use a script to go through a folder full of geodatabases, open each geodatabase, and rename the feature classes inside the same name as the geodatabase it resides in.

For example, for a folder like this....

```
MyFolder
   Geodatabase1.gdb
       Points, Polylines
   Geodatabase2.gdb
       Polylines
   Geodatabase3.gdb
       Points
```

I want...

```
MyFolder
   Geodatabase1.gdb
       Geodatabase1_Points, Geodatabase1_Polylines
   Geodatabase2.gdb
       Geodatabase2_Polylines
   Geodatabase3.gdb
       Geodatabase3_Points
```

My code to do this is giving me the error `arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Data Element. Failed to execute (Rename).` Can anyone see what might be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
outLocation = r"C:\Path\to\MyFolder"
arcpy.env.workspace = outLocation
MasterGDB = outlocation + 'excludedGDB.gdb'

for fgdb in arcpy.ListFiles():  

    if fgdb.endswith('.gdb') and fgdb != MasterGDB:

        arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(outLocation, fgdb)
        featureDataset = arcpy.ListDatasets()[0]
        featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset= featureDataset)

        for fc in featureClasses:
                in_data = fc
                out_data = fgdb +'_'  + fc
                data_type= "FeatureClass"
                arcpy.Rename_management(in_data, out_data, data_type)

    else:
        print fgdb + " is not a gdb or has been otherwise excluded."
```

Comment: With fgdb != MasterGDB you are comparing a geodatabase name (for example test123.gdb) with a full path and name to a geodatabase (C:\test\test3456.gdb). This will always be false. You should also take a look at os.path.join for combining paths and file names

Answer (score 4):

I have received this error because one of my feature classes (we'll call it 'featureA') was open in the table of contents when trying to do an arcpy.Copy_management ('featureA','featureAcopy')

It could be as simple as removing a layer from your TOC.